# fixed connectionStrings compile time error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've faced a problem that is:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code.
>   Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'lenovo'.

```
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Employee/


    public ActionResult index()
    {
        EmployeeContext employeecontext = new EmployeeContext();
        List <Employee> employee = employeecontext.Employees.ToList();


        return View(employee);
    }






    public ActionResult Details(int id)

    {
        EmployeeContext employeecontext = new EmployeeContext();
        Employee employee = employeecontext.Employees.Single(emp => emp.EmployeeId == id);


        return View(employee);
    }

}}
<connectionStrings>
<add name="EmployeeContext"
     connectionString="LENOVO=.; Database=ED; integrated security=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: when i entered http://localhost:50103/Employee/Details/1 then that problems occours

Comment: Shouldn't `LENOVO=.` be `Server=.` or `Server=LENOVO`?

Comment: now that error displayed An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception. and then i continue then its appear   
Line 53:   <connectionStrings>
Line 54:     <add name="EmployeeContext"
Line 55:        Server= "LENOVO ; Database=ED; integrated security=true"
Line 56:          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you passed is not a valid database connection string, Change it to this one:

```
<add name="EmployeeContext"
     connectionString="Server=LENOVO; Database=ED; integrated security=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient""/>
```

Comment: Displayed same error.. by the way my server name is LENOVO or database name is ED